# Emacs: Ctags table don't working on projectile plugin

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

After im use command  `projectile-regenerate-tags` and I get:

> Ctags excuberant don't be a command

Comment: So, is `ctags` a program installed on your system? If it is not that would explain the error message. What OS are you running Emacs on? (adding that information as a tag as well would be useful).

Comment: @verdammelt oc windows

Comment: Have you checked if ctags is installed on your system? My guess is that it is not and projectile (which depends upon ctags) cannot find it and the error you are seeing is telling you this.